# Mouse button 4 and 5 go back/forth twice in Discord

Tags: mouse

In Discord, pressing mouse button 4 or 5 goes back/forth both on button press and release. It doesn't happen anywhere else.

I've tried 2 mouses I had and several distros (and even ran a VM on Windows once), but the issue persisted in all of these scenarios. I'm assuming it's Discord's (or Electron's) fault, so I have no idea whether anything can be done about it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and I can confirm it's not my mouse. I have this happen with 2 different mice, and it even happens when using Barrier where linux is my client and windows my host. To add to that, the double back/forward does it in both Slack and Discord. When I open slack/discord on both windows and linux and use the same mouse to send the exact same back/forward key, in windows it works, on linux it does twice.

Comment: There are fixes for custom discord clients: https://betterdiscord.app/plugin/NavigationFix https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18322 https://github.com/LunNova/nixos-configs/blob/1c31dbf829cd9f5a911f3f90a2e645752d5864a4/packages/powercord/disable-back-handling.js.patch

Comment: Having the same issue on Firefox.